# LNK2001 error when compiling windows forms application with VC++ 2008

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2008, linker

I've been trying to write a small application which will work with mysql in C++. I am using MySQL server 5.1.41 and MySQL C++ connector 1.0.5. Everything compiles fine when i write console applications, but when i try to compile windows forms application exactly the same way (same libraries, same paths, same project properties) i get this errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __clrcall sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::getSavepointId(void)" (?getSavepointId@MySQL_Savepoint@mysql@sql@@$$FUAMHXZ)  test1.obj   test1
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __clrcall sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::getSavepointName(void)" (?getSavepointName@MySQL_Savepoint@mysql@sql@@$$FUAM?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)   test1.obj   test1
```

following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261377/lnk2001-error-when-compiling-apps-referencing-stlport-5-1-4-with-vc-2008), i've got this:

```
Undecoration of :- "?getSavepointId@MySQL_Savepoint@mysql@sql@@UEAAHXZ"
is :- "public: virtual int __cdecl sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::getSavepointId(void) __ptr64"

Undecoration of :- "?getSavepointName@MySQL_Savepoint@mysql@sql@@UEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ"
is :- "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::getSavepointName(void) __ptr64"
```

but what should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project + Properties, General, change Common Language Runtime support to /clr from /clr:pure

Comment: Thank you very much, i've waited so long

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with calling conventions.  I am not very familiar with managed C++, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec7sfckb%28VS.80%29.aspx) might help you.